# Sending BSON data through JQuery POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, base64, json.net, bson

I have a question about sending binary (`base64`) data through JQuery's post to an action in my MVC project. The `base64` data is a cropped image retrieved from a HTML5 canvas (cropping done through JCrop). It works fine with very small images - however on bigger Images I get nothing coming into my parameters of my controller's action. Here's the sample call:

```
    var temp = canv1.toDataURL("image/png");
    var base64 = temp.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    var image = { cropped : base64 };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Image/Upload",
        data: image,
        processData: false,
        success: function (e) {
            alert('Cropped Image saved!');
        },
        failure: function (e) {
            alert(e);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.d);
        }
    });
```

My controller is set up to receive the data as a `String` parameter in the action right now, but I'm not sure if that's entirely correct anyway, since I'm dealing with binary data I guess...

Now I understand my error handling is a little dicey there, but regardless why is it that bigger images do not get passed in at all, but smaller are okay? And also, I read that if you don't say `processData: false`, then data is passed in like a query string and so is subject to the 2048 character limit (don't quote me on that number, I know it's a small character limit can't remember exactly what it is).

Anyway, long story short I want to know how to pass the `base64` data into my controller using JQuery's post method, as BSON (since I read that BSON is more effcient for handling binary data anyway, as JSON is meant to handle string data). Also, I'm using **MongoDB** as back-end so it's probably better to be working with BSON anyway.

I've read that a good framework to use for this is **JSON.NET**, but I can't find information on converting base64 data into BSON and passing it through JQuery's post (at least this is what I want to happen).

I'm open to alternative solutions to my problem, but it's no good to suggest a File Upload control and just post the file, since I'm dealing with the cropped image from a canvas, and it does not exist as an image outside of this state (as far as I know).

Please help! If I'm on the wrong track altogether a kick in the right direction would be much-appreciated.

(ps: Also wanted to keep this as "async" as possible, to avoid full page refreshes).

Comment: Cropped image is an image after all so what is wrong with file upload?

Comment: the cropped image only exists on the client side though, it doesn't get saved until it reaches the controller.

Comment: In that case, you can use `FormData` and use it like:

`var image = '....';
var blob = new Blob([image], { type: "image/png"});
formData.append("image", blob);`

Comment: Here is a link for how to use `FormData` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However I was kind of hoping to deal directly with base64 and BSON rather then including extra types. I tried the FormData approach before and it worked - I just think it's strange that that's the only way I've seen it done...